# Button onclick and edittext

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-button

```
    for(int x = 1; x < i ; x++){
        // VIEWS
         TextView tvx = new TextView(this);
         EditText etx = new EditText(this);
         EditText editx = new EditText(this);
         // ADD VIEW
        //set properties

        ll1.addView(tvx);
        ll1.addView(etx);
        ll1.addView(editx);
            // sets the ingredient  and the amount and cal corresponding

        switch(x){

        case 1: tvx.setText("Chicken");
                etx.setText("200");
                editx.setText("100g");

            break;
        case 2:tvx.setText("eggs");
                etx.setText("350");
                editx.setText("100g");
            break;
        case 3:tvx.setText("Bacon");
                etx.setText("400");
                editx.setText("100g");

            break;
        case 4:
            tvx.setText("Salad");
            etx.setText("200");
            editx.setText("100g");

        }



        //  // // // // // // // 


        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


            }



        });
```

Hey guys my code includes a for loop such that it generates a row inclusive of a textview and 2 
edit text. How ever, i do not know what to put in the in the btn2 onClick method as i am having a problem trying to uniquely identify each edit text. 
For example i am unable to extract a particular input by the user if any of those edit text were to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get text from both editexts and compare to text that you've setted before.

```
     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (etx.getText.toString().matches("400")){
           //some code here
        } else if (etx.getText.toString().matches("200")){
            //some code here
        } 

       }
```

Comment: This is really not the best way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Set IDs for the TextView and EditText when adding the row using `textView.setId(int id);`

You'll then be able to reference them using the same id.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(id);
```